# spark_df.toPandas() converting null values to NaN instead of None - python 3.10

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, python-3.6, python-3.10

I have a spark dataframe like below and I am planning to replace NaN values to null/None in dataframe and converting to pandas DF. But when converting back to pandas DF, null/None values are becoming NaN again. This is happening with Python 3.10 only not with python 3.6

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
print(sys.version)
print(sys.version_info)

3.10.11 (main, Apr 20 2023, 19:02:41) [GCC 11.2.0]
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=10, micro=11, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

```
another_df = spark.createDataFrame([(float('nan'), 0.0),(0.0,float('nan'))])
another_df.show()

output -

+---+---+
| _1| _2|
+---+---+
|NaN|0.0|
|0.0|NaN|
+---+---+
```

replace function -->

```
another_df = another_df.replace(float('nan'), None, subset=['_2'])
another_df.show()

output

+---+----+
| _1|  _2|
+---+----+
|NaN| 0.0|
|0.0|null|
+---+----+
```

toPandas -->

```
another_df.toPandas()

output:

    _1  _2
0   NaN 0.0
1   0.0 NaN
```